# AngularJS watch not for whole dataset

Tags: angularjs

I have the following watch in my AngularJS controller:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('vm.currentDateScheduler', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        makeSomethingwithALotOfDatasets();
        });
```

e.g. 400 datasets are handled in method **makeSomethingwithALotOfDatasets**.
When I change a dataset now (delete, update or create) then **watchCollection**
is invoked for all 400 datasets. 
Is there a possibility to prohibit the watchCollection for the other 399 datasets - this question is because I will have the best performance which is possible.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at the `debounce technique`. With it you can control how often a certain function will be called. [There is a short article about it](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function).

To keep it simple, I'll use `debounce` function from [lo-dash](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#debounce) library and update your code to this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('vm.currentDateScheduler', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    makeSmthWithDebounce();
});

//makeSomethingwithALotOfDatasets will be called once after 100 ms from last calling of makeSmthWithDebounce function.
function makeSmthWithDebounce = _.debounce(makeSomethingwithALotOfDatasets, 100);
```

A little [example on plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v97Q5d?p=preview) which uses the same approach.

---

There is also `throttle technique`. It can be useful if you want to call function only once in particular period of time.

[Debounce vs. throttle](http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation):

> Both techniques answer the same question "How often a certain function can be called over time?" in different ways:
>
> - Debounce: Think of it as "grouping multiple events in one". Imagine
>     that you go home, enter in the elevator, doors are closing... and
>     suddenly your neighbor appears in the hall and tries to jump on the
>     elevator. Be polite! and open the doors for him: you are debouncing
>     the elevator departure. Consider that the same situation can happen
>     again with a third person, and so on... probably delaying the
>     departure several minutes.
> - Throttle: Think of it as a valve, it
>     regulates the flow of the executions. We can determine the maximum
>     number of times a function can be called in certain time. So in the
>     elevator analogy.. you are polite enough to let people in for 10 secs,
>     but once that delay passes, you must go!